# Variable value for another variable ansible

Tags: ansible

Sorry if there are many posts about variables inside variable my use case is different.
 Trying to access an element from a variable list "efs_list"  based on the index-number of the current host. There are three hosts in the inventory

```
  vars:
    efs_list:
      - efs1
      - efs2
      - efs3
    sdb_index: "{{ groups['all'].index(inventory_hostname) }}"
```

The values should be as follows 
  host1- efs1
  host2- efs2
  host3- efs3

Tried accessing it through efs_list.{{ sdb_index }}
for   `- debug: var=efs_list.{{ sdb_index }}` the output is as intended

```
ok: [10.251.0.174] => {
    "efs_list.0": "efs1"
}
ok: [10.251.0.207] => {
    "efs_list.1": "efs2"
}
ok: [10.251.0.151] => {
    "efs_list.2": "efs3"
}
```

But for

```
     - debug:
        msg: "{{ efs_list.{{ sdb_index }} }}"

fatal: [10.251.0.174]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected name or number. String: {{ efs_list.{{ sdb_index }} }}"}

---
- name: SDB Snapshots Creation
  hosts: all
  remote_user: "centos"
  become: yes
  vars:
    efs_list:
      - efs1
      - efs2
      - efs3
    sdb_index: "{{ groups['all'].index(inventory_hostname) }}" 

  tasks:
    - debug: var=efs_list.{{ sdb_index }}

    - debug:
        msg:  "{{ efs_list.{{ sdb_index }} }}"

    - name: Get  Filesystem ID
      become: false
      local_action: command aws efs describe-file-systems --creation-token "{{ efs_list.{{ sdb_index }} }}"
         --region us-east-1 --query FileSystems[*].FileSystemId --output text  
      register: fs_id
```

It should attribute the element of list to current index`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

[extract](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#extracting-values-from-containers) filter will do the job. The input of the filter must be a list of indices and a container (array in this case). The tasks below

```
- set_fact:
    sdb_index: "{{ [] + [ groups['all'].index(inventory_hostname) ] }}"
- debug:
    msg: "{{ sdb_index|map('extract', efs_list)|list }}"
```

give

```
ok: [host1] => {
    "msg": [
        "efs1"
    ]
}
ok: [host2] => {
    "msg": [
        "efs2"
    ]
}
ok: [host3] => {
    "msg": [
        "efs3"
    ]
}
```

If the hosts are not sorted in the inventory it's necessary to sort them in the play

```
- set_fact:
    my_hosts: "{{ groups['all']|sort }}"
- set_fact:
    sdb_index: "{{ [] + [ my_hosts.index(inventory_hostname) ] }}"
- debug:
    msg: "{{ sdb_index|map('extract', efs_list)|list }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The mapping works as intended. It is in the form of list and when I use it in aws cli command it is not useful as list.`- set_fact:
        efs_name: "{{ sdb_index|map('extract', tokens)|list }}"

    - name: Get  Filesystem ID
      become: false
      local_action: command aws efs describe-file-systems --creation-token {{ efs_name }}
         --region us-east-1 --query FileSystems[*].FileSystemId`
Inside the raw parameters the value is` [u'efs1'] ,  [u'efs2']`  instead the value should be `efs1  or efs2` etc..

Comment: This fixed  the issue `- set_fact: efs_name: "{{ sdb_index|map('extract', tokens)|list | first }}"`